# feature importance for each class in multiclass classification

Tags: python, decision-tree, multiclass-classification

I built a decision tree and it also gives me the feature importance for my classification. But how can I tell my program to give me the feature importance for each of my classes? To give me the overall feature importance I have this code:

```py
importances = tree.feature_importances_
#std = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in forest.estimators_],
            # axis=0)
indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]

# Print the feature ranking
print("Feature ranking:")

for f in range(X.shape[1]):
    print("%d. feature %d (%f)" % (f + 1, indices[f], importances[indices[f]]))

# Plot the feature importances of the forest
plt.figure()
plt.title("Feature importances")
plt.bar(range(X.shape[1]), importances[indices],
       color="r", yerr=std[indices], align="center")
plt.xticks(range(X.shape[1]), [feature_cols[i] for i in indices])
plt.xlim([-1, X.shape[1]])
plt.show()
```

I have four classes - 0, 1, 2, 3.
Does someone know a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue, isn't feature importance giving you an array for each feature? As said by the scikit-learn docs: `Returns: feature_importances_ : array, shape = [n_features]`

Comment: Yes, for each feature. But I want the feature importance for each class. So, I want the information for which class which feature is the most important one

Comment: @maybeyourneighour I was looking for the same thing and it seems that LIME package is the best solution https://github.com/marcotcr/lime